# Performance implications of multiple Virtual Hosts in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, web-server, virtualhost

The suspicion may be completely inaccurate, but my guts tell me running multiple `<VirtualHost>ServerName site.domain [...]</VirtualHost>`-statements on the same Apache server (same ip) means somewhere a "match" has to be made.

Let's look at two hypothetical situations. Let's say we have:

1. A server with 1 Virtual Host receiving 1.000 page requests, and
2. A server with 10 Virtual Hosts each receiving 100 page requests

In both cases the total number of req.s are 1.000.

So, my question is - would the server in the second case deliver responses slower?

---

*This question is of course not limited to Apache, but could be formulated in regards to, e.g. nginx instead using the `server{}`-statement.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it certainly will, but the impact of this is going to be totally insignificant compared to all the other stuff the server has to do and things like bandwidth constraints etc. will be a bottleneck a lot earlier than any slowdown by this vhost routing.

Comment: Meaning it is a theoretical slowdown but in reality something to simply disregard?

Comment: Yes. I doubt that you could even measure the impact of this.

Comment: Thank you for your response @SvenW. I was going to post a comeback thought on magnitudes of say 10.000 requests / second. But indeed I see that one will have other obvious problems to deal with forehand, rendering this issue a non-one.